# Switching between Ubuntu Flavors [Desktop Enviroment]

Tags: boot, dual-boot, lubuntu

I'm a new Linux user and just installed Ubuntu, wanted to try other Desktop Environments however it didn't work. It only loads up with the Lubuntu logo and Login screen, after that It's just Ubuntu. I ran this command:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

However I'm not sure how to switch back, I tried the purge command got rid of it now only black screen during loading.

Side Question: Dual Boot with Windows - Change Linux Dist without having to reformat entire Windows?

Answer (score 1):

There will be a gear or icon either near the password field or in the status bar on the login screen. If it's an icon, it will have the Ubuntu logo in it (if Unity is your default DE). Click it to choose another DE before logging in.

Comment: Perfect. It's so simple, but finally someone tells us how to get a menu from which we choose the desired desktop environment. Big +1.

Answer (score 1):

In case of problems with logging in: it could be that purging deleted a needed file in /home/$USER/ or it changed permissions on a needed file. If the problems occur before login it is more than likely related to the video card driver.

1st thing to do is to go to a TTY (<kbd>control alt f1</kbd>). You can use apt-get to re-install ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

(or any other desktop) or re-install your video card driver or re-configure your video card.

If that is not possible you can also do this from the grub prompt or from a live session.

As a future method of doing this: do not mess with your OS. Install virtual box or vm ware and install Ubuntu in that. Make a copy of the container and you can mess with desktops all day long. Restore the container and all is back to normal.

Comment: I have Ubuntu installed but It's not activated yet, only black screen shows at log in with user name, then password.