# Switching between Ubuntu Flavors

Tags: unity, lubuntu, desktop-environments

Is Ubuntu 16.04 same as Lubuntu 16.04 or Elementary OS Loki with the desktop environments changed? Can I install Elementary OS Loki and 'switch' to Ubuntu just by installing the Unity desktop environment?

My question is different from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791450/switching-between-ubuntu-flavors-desktop-enviroment) where the asker only wanted to switch between the desktop environments. I specifically want to know if the underlying codebase and kernel is same between all these flavors.

And lastly, if I have Elementary OS installed, is it possible to get updates from the latest Ubuntu repository?

Comment: and questions related to Elementary OS Loki are off topic.

Comment: For me, this seems to be a generic question, not actually related to the usage of Elementary OS. Fit for AU and Unix.SE in my opinion. But since community is agreeing it being closeable, I'm sharing the answer on a link. You can view [the answer here](https://stackedit.io/viewer#!provider=gist&gistId=bcde2743cbe790157905f68bb0a00bf6&filename=answer)